# (JavaScript) Random Text Output - Suggestions?

Tags: javascript, random

So what I have is http://garrettstelly.com which spits out one of twenty terms at startup.  The code is very heavy, and I'm fine with that.

I plan on making a website to spit out a name at random, the problem is that I can have an endless amount of names.  For the js that I'm using currently, I'm using a random roll and even portions between 0 and 1 to read the names.  The problem with that is that I can't ever add just one phrase, I'll have to add a chunk all at once for the probabilities to be even.

> How can I make a script with an endless amount of possibilities to be added one at a time?

here's the javascript for garrettstelly.com:

```
var roll = Math.random()
if (roll<0.05)
{document.write('<a href="http://www.facebook.com/abroheem.vonclinxenburg">Bro-Heem</a>');}
else if (roll<0.10)
{document.write('I am too white for my own good');}
else if (roll<0.15)
{document.write('I love the way you paste those stickers.');}
else if (roll<0.20)
{document.write('You probably were not just thinking about Wichita');}
else if (roll<0.25)
{document.write('Yummy, Adhesive!');}
else if (roll<0.30)
{document.write('<a href="http://www.rolex.com/">Rolex</a>');}
else if (roll<0.35)
{document.write('There is a 5% chance that you will see this when you first visit this website.');}
else if (roll<0.40)
{document.write('Making Money.<br>Choppas How We Do Today.');}
else if (roll<0.45)
{document.write('45, get your bills roll em high.');}
else if (roll<0.50)
{document.write('I WILL teach you how to fish');}
else if (roll<0.55)
{document.write('I am a gangsta.');}
else if (roll<0.60)
{document.write('Please get out of my website');}
else if (roll<0.65)
{document.write('<a href="http://www.facebook.com/luke.immel?fref=ts">derriere</a>');}
else if (roll<0.70)
{document.write('I think YOU are a Q T PIE');}
else if (roll<0.75)
{document.write('X=Fries');}
else if (roll<0.80)
{document.write("Idle hands are the Devil's playground.<br>The Devil is smaller than hands.");}
else if (roll<0.85)
{document.write('I am about to be late for class');}
else if (roll<0.90)
{document.write('"Hipster"');}
else if (roll<0.95)
{document.write('I am late for class');}
else
{document.write('Please refrain from drinking the water located within the wishing well, thank you.');}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript. Use an array, divide with it's length, and compare it with your roll. It's simple, try to figure it out.

Comment: @SoonDead But the example code provided is written in JavaScript... so this question has everything to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the possibilities in an array and get a random element of the array:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KMGQW/1/)

```
function getRandomName()
{
    var names = [
        'John',
        'Sue',
        'Bob',
        'Sandeep'
    ];

    return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
}

document.write( getRandomName() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put all the things you want spit out into an array. For example:

```
var arr = [
    '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/abroheem.vonclinxenburg">Bro-Heem</a>',
    'I am too white for my own good',
    // other entries...
    'Please refrain from drinking the water located within the wishing well, thank you.'
];
```

Then your roll should still be `Math.random()` but multiplied by the length of the array:

```
var roll = (Math.floor(Math.random()) * arr.length);
```

Then write your result with the appropriate array index, in your case by using `document.write` (though there may be better ways):

```
document.write(arr[roll]);
```

Now you can add to your array as much as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array:

```
var outputTextArr = ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3', 'text 4', 'more text', 'some text'];
```

Then randomly target the items in the array:

```
function randomRange(from, to){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}

var outputText = outputTextArr[randomRange(0, outputTextArr.length - 1)];//var output text will have a random item
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
var sentences = 
[
    "I am too white for my own good",
    "I love the way you paste those stickers.",
    "You probably were not just thinking about Wichita"
    // Add more sentences if you want to
];

var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * sentences.length);
alert(sentences[index]); // This will be your random value
```

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fGCci).